# No se puede imprimir con print() en navegador mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, print

buenos dias tengo este script

```js
function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
    <tbody><tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>      
        <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>Smith</td>      
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>        
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>        
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>Johnson</td>        
        <td>67</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>

<br />
<br />

<button>Print me</button>
```

en computadora todo va perfecto pero en versiones mobiles me sale que no se pudo procesar la impresion.
nota: lo provee desde varios dispositivos moviles y lo mismo.
parece ser que el problema es cuando genera la ventana about:blank.

Solicito porfavor su ayuda a alguien que ya le haya dado solucion.

gracias

Answer (score 0):

Como se indica claramente en la siguiente [documentación](http://wiki.nsbasic.com/Window.print()):

> "El comando es compatible con iOS, Chrome en Windows y Safari y Chrome
> en Mac. No es compatible con Android."

Los teléfonos Android aún no tienen soporte nativo para imprimir, por lo que **window.print()** no funcionará. Lo que significa que debes usar una aplicación de terceros para realizar la impresión. Puedes encontrar algunas alternativas en este [artículo](http://www.howtogeek.com/165778/everything-you-need-to-know-about-printing-from-your-android-phone-or-tablet/).

Comment: claro yo uso Rawbt; te explico el problema no es imprimir si no la vista previa para imprimir, es decir en el navegador chrome pc funciona perfecto con elementos creados dinamicamente pero en el navegador chrome para android no funciona, funciona imprimir paginas si pero no contenido creado con javascript dinamicamente